# Ajax loading new message after operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok i write ajax script for adding data to db. My problem is when i add data same message stay on, so its hard to see if new operation is completed. Is any way to hide message after showing it, and display new after next ajax operation . My code is

```
function change_data(id){

    var data = document.getElementById('update'+id).innerText;

  var new_data = prompt(data,'Unesite novi podatak!').trim();

 if(new_data !=='' && new_data !== null){
    $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'admin/crud/changes'?>",
    type: 'post',
    data: {'id' : id, 'new_data':new_data },
    success: function(resp){
          if(resp==""){

         $('#warning').html('Podatak je azuriran');

         $('#update'+id).html(new_data);

      }
    }
    });
}
```

in this part i add html to div, so i have same message, each time

```
 $('#warning').html('Podatak je azuriran');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set timeout function like this

```
$('#warning').html('Podatak je azuriran');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#warning').html('');
    $('#warning').hide('');
}, 2000);
```

where 2000 is the number of milliseconds after which you want to perform this function

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide it in success callback function:-

```
if(new_data !=='' && new_data !== null){

    $('#warning').html('Podatak je azuriran');

    $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'admin/crud/changes'?>",
    type: 'post',
    data: {'id' : id, 'new_data':new_data },
    success: function(resp){
          if(resp==""){

         $('#warning').html('');

         $('#update'+id).html(new_data);

      }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use fadeOut thats part of jquery like this: (sorry for no actual ajax call), it will make the element fade out over a number of milliseconds (the 1000 in this code block, or 2000 in the linked demo).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button').click(function () {
                $('#MessageOutput').show();
                $('#MessageOutput').html("Sending data..");
                // Do ajax call

                // In "Success":
                $('#MessageOutput').html("Data transfer done");
                $('#MessageOutput').fadeOut(1000);
                //$('#MessageOutput').delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
                //$('#MessageOutput').delay(2000).hide(0); 
                // Note: In the last example: you must supply a 
                // 0 as an argument for .hide(), otherwise hide is not animated, and won't
                // be delayed by .delay (it will just hide it immediately
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="Button">asdasd</button>
    <div id="MessageOutput">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2vk2bbz7/4/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery delay and fadeout function

```
$('#warning').html('Podatak je azuriran').delay(3000).fadeOut(300)
```

Comment: try calling fadeIn frist to make div visible if not already visible $('#warning').html('Podatak je azuriran').fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut(300)

Answer (score 0):

you can make the warning div empty once you call the function again 
or you can empty the warning  div when you fill it after 3 or 5 second 
use  javascript function "setTimeout"